# UITableView: first tap of the cell not received

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

I have UITableView on UIViewController with content a little bit larger then table's area. When I try to set bounces property to NO, the first tap of the cell stopes to receive after scrolling table to bounds.

I created a test project to receive all nuances of this problem:

1) first selection works fine before scrolling;

2) second selection after scrolling works fine too;

3) there is no problem, if scroll comes to the bounds itself (instead i'll scroll with finger and will end touch after came to the bounds);

4) set bounces property to YES solves problem (bcs scroll can comes to the bounds only itself);

5) highlights of the cell works always;

6) next delegate methods not received (ofcourse only when bug fired)

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

**UPD:** here's gif with bug, seems that scroll bar not hiding too, when this bug fires

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an Apple's bug of UITableView that needs to report. Here some way to veil the problem (not good, but effective):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    if (!scrollView.bounces) {
        targetContentOffset->y = -1;
    }
}
```